# Problem with importing program for coding

Tags: pandas, python-import, helper

I am trying to extract stock data and the first part of importing the programs says this message.

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_23208/566689617.py in <module>
----> 1 import pandas_datareader.data as web
      2 import datetime
      3 import pandas as pd

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'
```

Comment: Please can you reformat your error message using the code functionality provided by SO?. This error means you're trying to import a libray Python cannot find, in this case `pandas_datareader`. To read to DataFrames, pandas provides you with functions like `read_csv` or `read_excel` and a lot more. So `import pandas as pd` gives you this ability. By googling, I find that there is a module named `pandas_datareader`. [https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) Did you install it?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing pandas_datareader:

`pip install pandas-datareader`